# C++ optimization: avoid a copy operation

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization, move-semantics, copy-elision

I have the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

class T {
public:
    T() {std::cout << "Default constructor called" << std::endl;}
    T(const T&) {std::cout << "Copy constructor called" << std::endl;}
};

static T s_t;

T foo() {
    return s_t;
}

class A {
public:
    A() = delete;
    A(T t) : _t(t) {}
private:
    T _t;
};

int main() {

    std::cout << "Starting main" << std::endl;
    A a(foo());
    return 0;

}
```

When I compile it with the line:
`g++ -std=c++17 -O3 test.cpp` and run it, I get the following output

```
Default constructor called
Starting main
Copy constructor called
Copy constructor called
```

My question is: since the constructor of `A` is taking an r-value object of type `T` that is only used to initialize `_t`, is it possible for the compiler to avoid the second copy operation and just copy `s_t` directly into `_t`?

(I understand that I can potentially replace the second copy with a move by implementing a move constructor for `T`)

Comment: NRVO is not required to be elided

Comment: @AndyG that's not even NRVO - NRVO refers to return of  local variables.

Comment: @AndyG ...and what is elided is the copy, not the optimization ;)

Comment: `g++ -std=c++17 test.cpp -o test` -- Please turn on optimizations, rebuild, and then give us the results.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie That won't change the output. The copy constructor has a side effect and is not used in a context where elision is allowed, so you will observe those side effects.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie even with highest level of optimizations it's not going to be elided

Comment: Notice than compiler elides one copy for `A(T t)` with `t == foo()`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Good point for [past C++ versions](https://godbolt.org/z/e6oKgk), but since C++17 there is no copy there, not even conceptually: https://godbolt.org/z/l1Ibdy

Answer (score 1):

Your copy constructor has an observable side effect (output). The (almost) golden rule of C++ optimizations is the **as-if rule**: Observable side effects must not be changed. But one of the two exceptions from this rule is the elision of some copy operations, specified here:

http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.elision

> When certain criteria are met, an implementation is allowed to omit the copy/move construction of a class object, even if the constructor selected for the copy/move operation and/or the destructor for the object have side effects.

But this is only allowed in very specific circumstances:

> This elision of copy/move operations, called copy elision, is permitted in the following circumstances (which may be combined to eliminate multiple copies):
>
> - in a return statement in a function with a class return type, when the expression is the name of a non-volatile **automatic** object [...]

Your variable does not have automatic storage duration (i.e. it is not a local variable).

> - in a throw-expression, [...]

We are not a throw-expression.

> - in a coroutine [...]

We are not in a coroutine.

> - when the exception-declaration of an exception handler ([except]) declares an object of the same type (except for cv-qualification) as the exception object ([except.throw]) [...]

This is not the case either.

Neither the return of a global variable from a function, nor the use of a constructor parameter to initialize a member variable is covered here, so it would be illegal for any compiler to elide these copies in the code you show.

That said, if the compiler can prove that there are no side effects (which, in the case of most compilers, include system calls and memory allocations), it is of course free to elide the copy under the as-if rule, just like for all other optimizations.

Comment: Thanks @MaxLanghof. I wonder why this case is not allowed by the specification.

Comment: @jmoxoby - It's not allowed because in the scope of the c'tor you have two declared objects (the member and the parameter). Since you declared an object there, it must exist, meaning it must be initialized. The compiler can't just make it disappear as easily as one may want.